# Classify movies based on their ratings using their subtitles-accuracy very bad

Tags: nlp, tokenize, text-classification, naivebayes, svc

I have a data set of 130 movies and their subtitles.I have to classify them based on their ratings (R,NR,PG,PG-13,G).(language used python)
I did the following:
1)tokenized the data using treebank whitespace and wordpunc tokenizers.
2)lemmatized the data.(lemmatization gave more accuracy when pos tags were included. )
3)removed stop words and punctuation.
4)for movies belonging to each class, performed tfidf vectorization and picked the top 1000 words using max_features and constructed a data frame of size 125 *5000.
5)I applied several classification and clustering algorithms and they gave me the following accuracy:
SVC: test accuracy :0.325 and train accuracy :0.63
Naive Bayes: test acc:0.25 and train accuracy :0.33
knn: test accuracy : 0.41
kmeans:test accuracy:0.162
Logistic regression: test accuracy:0.53 and training accuracy of : 0.96

What should I do to improve my accuracy?
Am I making any mistakes or missing out on something important?

Comment: See if this helps : https://github.com/mesutgurlek/Movie-Category-Classification-from-Subtitles/blob/master/final%20presentation.pdf  it tries to predict genre, rating is a similar problem.

Answer (score 0):

You're lucky enough to have data you can understand intuitively. Try picking a few examples of misclassification and try to determine why your model failed.

- Are you accidentally filtering out swear words? Perhaps an n-gram model would be more predictive
- Do you have timing as well as text? Gaps in dialogue may indicate emotional or action scenes